# TypeORM Performance problem - Loading object with many relations

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, query-performance, typeorm

TS + Node 12 + TypeORM + MySQL - AWS 2GB instance EC2 (medium I think)

The issue is simple.

For get orders API request - we load orders from the database - each order comes with more related fields from other tables - via join. Something like:

```
const galleries: Gallery[] = await relationshipAModel.createQueryBuilder('model')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('model.subRelationshipA', 'a')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('model.subRelationshipB', 'b')
      .whereInIds(firstResultIds)
      .getMany();
```

The code is from: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/4499

Our issue is the exact same issue as linked here.

NodeJS process crashes when loading 5-10 requests - each request loads 500 orders - loading 25 / 50 / 100 orders is ok.

Memory profiling didn't help.

Order object in typescript looks like:

```
@Entity()
export class Order {
@PrimaryColumn({ type: 'varchar', name: 'id' })
id: string;

@OneToMany(type => OrderItem, orderItem => orderItem.order, {
    cascade: true
})
orderItems: OrderItem[];

@ManyToOne(type => ServiceLevel, serviceLevel => serviceLevel.orders, {
    cascade: true
})
serviceLevel: ServiceLevel;

@ManyToOne(type => Customer, customer => customer.orders, { cascade: true })
customer: Customer;

@JoinColumn()
@OneToOne(type => Address, { cascade: true, nullable: true })
shippingAddress: Address;

@JoinColumn()
@OneToOne(type => Address, { cascade: true, nullable: true })
billingAddress: Address;

@ManyToMany(type => OrderTag, orderTag => orderTag.orders, {
    cascade: true
})
@JoinTable()
orderTags: OrderTag[];
```

Left only the fields that are "suspects"

Node heap stack for 350 orders:

```
Nov 25 15:24:58 ip-172-31-38-186 web: {
Nov 25 15:24:58 ip-172-31-38-186 web: page: 0,
Nov 25 15:24:58 ip-172-31-38-186 web: maxResults: 350,
Nov 25 15:24:58 ip-172-31-38-186 web: filters: [ { fieldName: 'orderStatus', operator: 'NOT IN', values: [Array] } ],
Nov 25 15:24:58 ip-172-31-38-186 web: stepFilter: { fieldName: 'orderStatus', operator: 'IN', values: [ 'stepPrint' ] },
Nov 25 15:24:58 ip-172-31-38-186 web: sortFields: [ { fieldName: 'createdDate', value: 'DESC' } ]
Nov 25 15:24:58 ip-172-31-38-186 web: }
Nov 25 15:25:18 ip-172-31-38-186 web: <--- Last few GCs --->
Nov 25 15:25:18 ip-172-31-38-186 web: [20326:0x31ad300]   113205 ms: Mark-sweep 993.9 (999.1) -> 993.7 (997.4) MB, 766.6 / 0.0 ms  (+ 127.3 ms in 23 steps since start of marking, biggest step 25.9 ms, walltime since start of marking 969 ms) (average mu = 0.231, current mu = 0.082) allocation [20326:0x31ad300]   114167 ms: Mark-sweep 994.1 (997.4) -> 993.2 (997.1) MB, 881.2 / 0.0 ms  (+ 47.2 ms in 7 steps since start of marking, biggest step 26.7 ms, walltime since start of marking 963 ms) (average mu = 0.138, current mu = 0.036) allocation fa
Nov 25 15:25:18 ip-172-31-38-186 web: <--- JS stacktrace --->
Nov 25 15:25:18 ip-172-31-38-186 web: ==== JS stack trace =========================================
Nov 25 15:25:18 ip-172-31-38-186 web: 0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x13555cd]
Nov 25 15:25:18 ip-172-31-38-186 web: Security context: 0x003cbef008d1 <JSObject>
Nov 25 15:25:18 ip-172-31-38-186 web: 1: slice [0x2c5dd3dc3561] [buffer.js:~606] [pc=0xb6e02716b7c](this=0x3b080493db19 <Object map = 0x3047472a6099>,0x3b0942d12c71 <Uint8Array map = 0x3047472a55a9>,44922,45232)
Nov 25 15:25:18 ip-172-31-38-186 web: 2: _typeCast(aka typeCast) [0x20293188c3e9] [/var/app/current/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/packets/RowDataPacket.js:~53] [pc=0xb6e027ab692](this=0x338ac1d1b739 <RowDataPacket map =...
Nov 25 15:25:18 ip-172-31-38-186 web: FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
Nov 25 15:25:18 ip-172-31-38-186 web: 1: 0xa093f0 node::Abort() [node]
Nov 25 15:25:18 ip-172-31-38-186 web: 2: 0xa097fc node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) [node]
Nov 25 15:25:18 ip-172-31-38-186 web: 3: 0xb842ae v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
Nov 25 15:25:18 ip-172-31-38-186 web: 4: 0xb84629 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
Nov 25 15:25:18 ip-172-31-38-186 web: 5: 0xd30fe5  [node]
Nov 25 15:25:18 ip-172-31-38-186 web: 6: 0xd31676 v8::internal::Heap::RecomputeLimits(v8::internal::GarbageCollector) [node]
Nov 25 15:25:18 ip-172-31-38-186 web: 7: 0xd3def5 v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
Nov 25 15:25:18 ip-172-31-38-186 web: 8: 0xd3eda5 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
Nov 25 15:25:18 ip-172-31-38-186 web: 9: 0xd4185c v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFail(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [nod
e]
```

Any help will be much apperciated!

Comment: Please provide the SQL from `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Possibly the many-to-many tables can be improved as outlined here: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

Comment: Thank you @RickJames - here it is - https://pastebin.com/3WiBcmQb - Let me know

Comment: What does a typical `id` look like?  (`VARCHAR(255)` does not sound good.)  5 Unique keys?  Probably bad design.  What if a guy with a single billing address wants to ship something to his girlfriend and something to a different girlfriend?  Let's see the SQL for the query, too.

Comment: Thanks again @RickJames. id is composed out of shop_id + order number from the shop, Something like "1_882972974". Any advise to make it better?

And - can you elaborate a bit about what is wrong with 5 unique keys? 

I will get the SQL query soon.

Comment: Added the query @RickJames - https://pastebin.com/m8yvVHq4

Again - much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `id` is the `PRIMARY KEY` for `order`, then the `DISTINCT` is unnecessary.

A `LIMIT` should have an `ORDER BY`.

`order` needs

```
 INDEX(shopId, orderBatchId, id)
```

A hundred columns for 100 rows?  That seems like a lot.  Rethink which columns you really need and whether you need 100 rows.

Are there nodejs or "packet" or other networking limits?  (Since 100 rows, but 500 croaks.)

5 Unique keys implies that there *could* be a separate table that equates 4 of them to one.  It also implies that there is *probably* a design error; I commented on another question that had both `shipping_addr` and `billing_addr` being `UNIQUE`.  If I try to send something to two relatives at different addresses, I will have trouble.  Especially if anyone else is using your system to send to either of those addresses.

Even 3 `UNIQUEs` is probably a mistake.  I know of *very* few valid cases for 2 `UNIQUEs`; the common one is for 'normalization'.

This construct makes my head spin.  I need to figure out if it does what you wanted:

```
FROM a  LEFT JOIN b  INNER JOIN c
```

If that is equivalent to this, then you don't have what you wanted:

```
FROM a  LEFT JOIN (b  INNER JOIN c)
```

This, on the other hand, is probably what you wanted:

```
FROM (a  LEFT JOIN b)  INNER JOIN c
```

This would clearer, especially since `c` is a subquery:

```
FROM (c  JOIN a)  LEFT JOIN b
```

Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` so we can see how it was evaluated.

Meanwhile, if you can get the subquery *first*, my quandry is avoided.  And it *may* help performance.

`LEFT` -- Are you using `LEFT JOIN` because each of those things may be missing data?  For example, might the `shippingAddress` be missing (and you are expecting `NULLs`)?  I ask because it makes a difference to performance, readability, optimization, etc.  Use `LEFT` when needed, else don't.